# Calling powershell cmdlets in powershell script

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-cmdlet

How do i use powershell cmdlets in a ps script??
I need to use Get-MailboxStatistics cmdlet to retrieve mailbox statistics from Exchange server 2013 using a ps script

how can i invoke the cmdlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using PowerShell's own help with:

```
Get-Help Get-MailboxStatistics -Full
```

Then you can investigate parameters such as -Server -Identity.

The -Full parameter will give you examples.

Comment: Thankyou...but i was hoping to retrieve statistics from a remote server..i had found the way by implicit remoting..thanks anyway :)